# Service Worker served from different port on a local machine

Tags: django, proxy, gruntjs, localhost, service-worker

I'm trying to develop a PWA for our sites. In production and staging, we serve everything from one domain. However, in development on a local machine we serve HTML from one port using Django server eg

`http://localhost:8000`

And the assets (including JS) using Grunt server from another port:

`http://localhost:8001`

The problem is that the scope of the service workers is therefore only limited to assets, which is useless, I want to offline-cache pages on the 8000-port origin.

I have somewhat been able to go around this by serving the service worker as a custom view in Django:

```
# urls.py

url(r'^(?P<scope>.*)sw\.js', service_worker_handler)

# views.py

def service_worker_handler(request, scope='/'):
    return HttpResponse(render_to_string('assets/sw.js', {
        'scope': scope,
    }), content_type="application/x-javascript")
```

However, I do not think this is a good solution. This code sets up custom routing rules which are not necessary for production at all.

What I'm looking for is a local fix using a proxy, or something else that would let me serve the service worker with grunt like all the other assets.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this resource can be of help to you: https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/foreign-fetch/

Basically you host the Service worker on the port 8001 and the server handles it as shown in the example.
Then you fetch it from there.

The Foreign fetch is described more in details here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/09/foreign-fetch

Comment: Foreign fetch is no longer supported in chrome and does not make it to  recent service worker specs